# Объединить вложенные списки и числа в один список Python

Tags: python, list

Решил пройти задание на CheckiO, где требуется объединить вложенные списки и числа в один список, например:

([-1, [1, [-2], 1], -1]) == [-1, 1, -2, 1, -1]

([1, [2, 2, 2], 4]) == [1, 2, 2, 2, 4]

Кто подскажет, в чём ошибка и как её исправить?

```
from itertools import chain

def flat_list(array):
lst_one = []
lst_two = []
for i in array:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        lst_one.append(i)
    if isinstance(i, int):
        lst_two.append(i)

combined = chain(lst_one, lst_two)
return list(combined)
```

Answer (score 3):

Наверное самым логичным решением здесь будет рекурсивная функция.

```
array_to_parse_1 = ([-1, [1, [-2], 1], -1])
array_to_parse_2 = ([1, [2, 2, 2], 4])


def parse_list(input_array):
    result_array = []
    for array_item in input_array:
        if isinstance(array_item, list) or isinstance(array_item, tuple):
            result_array.extend(parse_list(array_item))
        else:
            result_array.append(array_item)
    return result_array


print(parse_list(array_to_parse_1))
print(parse_list(array_to_parse_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что по этому условию `if isinstance(i, list)` вы добавляете в список вложенные списки, а `chain` сцепляет эти списки с числами. Исправить, как уже сказали, можно использовав рекурсию. Есть еще вариант с генератором, например такой генератор справляется со всеми типами (кроме строк):

```
def flat_list(array):
    for i in array:
        if hasattr(i, '__iter__'):
            yield from flat_list(i)
        else: 
            yield i

l = [-1, [1, [-2], 1], -1, (3, -3), {4:5, 6:7}, [range(8,10), [11, 12, {(13,14):15}]]]
print([*flat_list(l)])
#------^-распаковка
'''
[-1, 1, -2, 1, -1, 3, -3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```