Python, каким образом можно объединить матрицу в список без циклов?
Например, есть матрица
 [['1', '4', '9', '9', '4', '7'], ['6', '9', '8', '6', '7', '4'],
 ['1', '1', '6', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '4', '5', '8', '7', '5'],
 ['6', '7', '8', '1', '1', '0'], ['6', '9', '9', '9', '7', '7']]

Как можно объединить эту матрицу в список lst=[] БЕЗ циклов?
Чтобы получился список lst=['1', '4', '9', '9', '4', '7','6', '9', '8', '6', '7', '4','1', '1', '6', '1', '1', '1','1', '4', '5', '8', '7', '5','6', '7', '8', '1', '1', '0', '6', '9', '9', '9', '7', '7']?

Такие вопросы были, поищите. Может быть, со словом "плоский", "flatten"

ТС, перекиньте галочку на ответ с итертулс. Он верный и лучше использовать его в решении данной задачи

https://dev.to/turbaszek/flat-map-in-python-3g98

@Qwertiy Хорошие результаты для list comprehension

Если можно с библиотекой itertools
import itertools


s=[['1', '4', '9', '9', '4', '7'], ['6', '9', '8', '6', '7', '4'],
 ['1', '1', '6', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '4', '5', '8', '7', '5'],
 ['6', '7', '8', '1', '1', '0'], ['6', '9', '9', '9', '7', '7']]
l =  list(itertools.chain(*s))

print(l)

['1', '4', '9', '9', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8', '6', '7', '4', '1', '1', '6', '1', '1', '1', '1', '4', '5', '8', '7', '5', '6', '7', '8', '1', '1', '0', '6', '9', '9', '9', '7', '7']

Дисклеймер
start
Нет причин не доверять словам и замечаниям от @strawdog.
Не рекомендуется использовать. Причины:

не масштабируемость
квадратичная сложность O(n^2)

Как вариант оставлю, потому что это решает проблему, хоть и не эффективно и как говорят грязный хак. Пользуйтесь на свой страх и риск
end
Вот такое решение
matrix = [['1', '4', '9', '9', '4', '7'], ['6', '9', '8', '6', '7', '4'],
          ['1', '1', '6', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '4', '5', '8', '7', '5'],
          ['6', '7', '8', '1', '1', '0'], ['6', '9', '9', '9', '7', '7']]

lst = sum(matrix, [])

Метод sum() используется как знак + для всех объектов основного (верхнего) списка. Если суммировать списки, то применяется конкатенация. Следовательно, вы просто друг за другом скидываете все списки в один.
Такой метод применим для любых built-in последовательностей, исключая словари и множества.
Про + можно почитать разобранный вопрос Что такое + в Python?
UPD
Про второй параметр можно найти в оф доке.
Данный параметр задает начальное значение, к которому будут суммироваться все итерируемые объекты последовательности. По умолчанию этот параметр равен 0, и является типом данных int. Если мы не определим в вашем примере начальное значение типа list мы получим исключение
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Поскольку операция сложения между типами данных list и int не определено

Спасибо, с методом sum() знаком давно, но про второй параметр никогда не слышал. Можете объяснить зачем он тут?

@pythonniy_chainik на здоровье, дополнил ответ

@pythonniy_chainik этот способ не рекомендован к использованию и является "грязным хаком", по меньшей мере по двум причинам - он не масштабируем и он наименее эффективен (O(n**2))

@strawdog я не погружался, может так и есть, но в офдоке, если вы прочтете, то там не стоит ограничение на использование для таких объектов. Есть рекомендация использовать iterools, причем не строгая. Но кто же нас останавливает применять такие вещи? Допишу дисклеймер со ссылкой на вас...

@strawdog на счет не масштабируемости не совсем уловил, со сложностью согласен полностью. У itertools она будет линейной и лучше использовать его

Вроде это list comprehension, а не цикл? tio.run
a = [['1', '4', '9', '9', '4', '7'], ['6', '9', '8', '6', '7', '4'],
     ['1', '1', '6', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '4', '5', '8', '7', '5'],
     ['6', '7', '8', '1', '1', '0'], ['6', '9', '9', '9', '7', '7']]

l = [x for b in a for x in b]

print(l)


А если ещё запретить ключевое слово for? И без импортов?

@StanislavVolodarskiy, ну для данных из вопроса - вот: eval("[" + "".join("".join(str(a).split("[")).split("]")) + "]") :D

@Qwertiy Только не eval ))  А то через eval можно и for из букв сначала собрать ))

itertools.chain.from_iterable:
import itertools

m = [
    ['1', '4', '9', '9', '4', '7'], ['6', '9', '8', '6', '7', '4'],
    ['1', '1', '6', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '4', '5', '8', '7', '5'],
    ['6', '7', '8', '1', '1', '0'], ['6', '9', '9', '9', '7', '7']
]
lst = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(m))
print(lst)

Без импортов, циклов и списковых включений:
def flatten(m):
    it = iter(m)
    lst = []
    
    def rec():
        try:
            lst.extend(next(it))
        except StopIteration:
            return
        rec()

    rec()
    return lst


m = [
    ['1', '4', '9', '9', '4', '7'], ['6', '9', '8', '6', '7', '4'],
    ['1', '1', '6', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '4', '5', '8', '7', '5'],
    ['6', '7', '8', '1', '1', '0'], ['6', '9', '9', '9', '7', '7']
]
lst = flatten(m)
print(lst)

P.S. Ещё можно убрать ограничение на глубину рекурсии.
P.P.S. ... и обойтись без исключений.
P.P.P.S. ... и выписать всё в одну строку.

Я бы рекурсию отдельным ответом постил.

@Qwertiy так вроде же был вопрос с неоднородным списком и разной степенью вложенности списков. Один из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1391173/209304

@Dmitry, не понял.
